# How to reset password Ubuntu from command prompt?

Tags: password

I want to update my system through this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jsr:
```

But when I enter it, my system asks for password, but I don't remember it.

How can I reset it?

Comment: no my computer is system is alreaddy login how can i change my password with command prompt

Comment: You will need to enter your password for changing it. otherwise, anyone come and without knowing your password, change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not reset a password without remembering your last password. You can however change your password if you do remember it by executing:

```
passwd
```